# How to fix a blank screen when editing post with image wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, editing

In my Wordpress news site when i try to edit a post that contain a image the editing paga simply don't load, showing a blank screen, in posts without images the edit function works as expected.

I've tried to tweek some options in the theme but nothing seems to work. I don't know if is plugin related an im a little cautious to deactivate all plugins

When inspecting the blank page the console shows these 4 erros:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token false
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined
>       at HTMLDocument. (wp-auth-check.min.js:1)
>       at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php:3)
>       at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php:3)
>       at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php:3)
>       at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php:8)
>       at HTMLDocument. (load-scripts.php:3)
>       at Function.each (load-scripts.php:2)
>       at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php:2)
>       at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php:3)
>       at Object. (load-scripts.php:27)
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Object

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using?
Are you using any kind of page builder?

Comment: The page biulder plugin is called JNews, the site is a local news page. The wordpress version is 5.2.1

Comment: I assume Jnews has a conflict with Guttenburg.
 The possible solution,
 1. Using Classic Editor (you can install classic editor plugin)
2. Update the theme menually.